# Using sqlplus to programmatically check connection

Tags: .net, oracle, process, sqlplus

Is it possible to use sqlplus to programmatically check a database connection (in particular, the SYS account)?

I'm thinking something along this line

1. Run sql plus (using Process.Start) with some parameter, giving the sys username and password
2. Check the exit code (or even the stdout), whether it is successful or not. The best way I can come up so far is to check the stdout string whether the substring "ERROR" exist, but I don't think this is very clean

Is this something possible? What parameter do you suggest I use?
The reason I want to do this is because System.Data.OracleClient [doesn't support connection as SYSDBA](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/23462bba-aafd-4a12-96b9-03531166667f/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work

```
whenever sqlerror exit failure
whenever oserror exit failure
conn user/pwd@db-name
select 'success' from dual;
exit
```

The above script will have the following behaviour:

- sqlplus process will return non-zero code if there was an error
- Otherwise sqlplus will return zero

Note that I haven't tested the above.

**Amendment**

The script should be run as follows on unix:

```
sqlplus -nolog @script-file.sql
```

And as follows on windows:

```
sqlplus /nolog @script-file.sql
```

Comment: this doesn't exit on failure.. Maybe the error doesn't classify as sqlerror or oserrror?

Comment: @Louis How are you running the above script? See amended section of post.

Comment: Fyi, I had to use "/nolog" instead of "-nolog" for 'SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production' (Win32). e.g. sqlplus /NOLOG @test.sql

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to get a session to check that the connection is running.

If you try to access the database using invalid credentials you'll get a ORA-01017 error. If the connection is not available or the listener is running but the database is not mounted (i.e. it can't check the credentials even though it can connect) you'll get a different error code.

See also the Nagios [check_oracle_v2](http://exchange.nagios.org/components/com_mtree/attachment.php?link_id=2015&cf_id=24) script for an example.

Answer (score 0):

I had [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40840765/how-to-verify-sqlplus-can-connect). I discovered we could specify what failure code could be sent depending on the case:

```
sqlplus /nolog << EOF
 WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 50
 WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 66
 connect /@${MISTERY_DB}
 exit;
EOF
```

Then to check the return code:

```
RET_CODE=$?
if [ ${RET_CODE} -eq 50 ] ; then
  echo "it was an SQLERROR"
fi
```